# Unable to convert parameter in constructor due to const

Tags: c++, constructor, const-cast

In my software I have a triangle and a page contain a triangle. I want to construct a page giving it a triangle plus other data.

```
class Triangle
{
public:
    const int **m_apVertex;
    Triangle(const int * apVertex[])
    {
        m_apVertex=apVertex;
    }
};

struct args
{
    int ** vertices;
    // ... other data
};

class Page
{
public:
    Triangle m_t;

    Page(const args conArgs):
        //m_t(const_cast<const INT **>(conArgs.vertices))
        m_t(conArgs.vertices)
    {
    }
};

void main()
{
    args a;
    Page p(a);
}
```

Compilation fail with:

```
error C2664: 'Triangle::Triangle(const int *[])' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int **const ' to 'const int *[]'
```

As a fix I use `m_t(const_cast<const INT **>(conArgs.vertices))` but I'm not sure why it won't work without const_cast;

Comment: Because you pass the argument to the `Page` constructor using `const`, that makes `conArgs.vertices` constant, which is different from an array of pointer to constant integers (or a non-constant pointer (as arrays decays to pointers) to pointers to constant integers). `const int **` is not the same as `int ** const`.

Comment: So the const modifier in `const args conArgs` in Page constructor makes `conArgs.vertices`` of type `int ** const`

Comment: In case you didn't know, you read the types right to left to make sense of them. So `int ** const var` reads: var is a const pointer to pointer to int. You cannot change where the pointer points to, but you are allowed to change what it points to. So `*var` is `int*` (not `const int*`) and `**var` is `int` (not `const int`). On the other hand `const int **m_apVertex` does not allow to change the value of the int that `*m_apVertex` points to, but you can change where `*m_apVertex`  points to and where `m_apVertex`  points to. If you want everytrhing const you can write `const int* const* const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should suffice to change:

```
const int **m_apVertex;
Triangle(const int * apVertex[])
```

to

```
 int **m_apVertex;
Triangle( int * apVertex[])
```

or if you dont want to touch it then change:

```
struct args
{
    int ** vertices;
```

to

```
struct args
{
    const int ** vertices;
```

Some additional info:

```
const int **m_apVertex;
^^^^^~~ this const is known as low-level const

const int ** const apVertex
             ^^^^^~~ this const is known as top-level const
```

top-level const is used to indicate that the pointer (whole object) itself is a const. If object to which pointer points is const, then we call it low-level const.

Now when we copy an object, top-level consts are ignored, so below is valid:

```
void foo(int* pi) {}
int main() {
    int* const pi=0;
    foo(pi);
}
```

same as in your case. But low-level const is never ignored, so you cannot do this:

```
const int ** cvertices;
int ** vertices;
vertices = cvertices;
```